# Flutter readAsBytesSync file read incomplete to encode base64

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, base64, imagepicker

1. List item

I'm trying to send a JPG image (captured by ImagePicker in emulator) via HTTP POST with base64 encoding to an AWS REST API. But readAsBytesSync() operation only reads a (head) part of the image (I've tested it printing to the string as bytes) thus base64 can only encode that small part. What may be the reason, many thanks for your help in advance.

```
  Future<void> captureImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    try {
      ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera,
          preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
                 String theimagepath = pickedFile.path.toString();
        //_imageFile = imageFile;
       
        print('theimagepath just below');
        print(theimagepath);
         
           String img64 = base64Encode(Io.File(theimagepath).readAsBytesSync());
           //print('bytes'+bytes.toString());
         
           print('img64:   '+img64);
 _imageFile = Io.File(pickedFile.path);


      setState(() {
        print('State here is ');
```

```
------------- DEBUG OUTPUT BELOW (base64 encoded string is incomplete) -------------

I/flutter (13629): theimagepath just below
I/flutter (13629): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.blabla/files/Pictures/f8a0295e-9ce5-446c-91d2-41c938e49b7f5430316734413263510.jpg
I/flutter (13629): img64:   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
I/flutter (13629): State here is
```

Comment: Have you proven that `readAsBytesSync()` is not reading the entire file?  Have you compared the `File(theimagepath).readAsBytesSync().length` with the actual file size observed on the filesystem (`File(theimagepath).lengthSync()`)?  How big is the file?

Comment: Both is 87590. File is JPG. Exported via Android Studio Device manager to linux files system, it also says 87590. But output is still is incoplete.

Comment: If `readAsBytesSync()` returned a `Uint8List` with the correct length, it certainly seems like it read the entire file.  How have you determined that it is incomplete?  Have you inspected the file itself to ensure that it contains all of the data that you expect?

Comment: I send it to AWS API, an it says: "TypeError: Incorrect padding". As you can see the above output window screen the encoded string is not complete (very short). I manually produced a base64 and compared with it (Their head part seem identical) but this is incomplete.Printing bytes to the screen also incomplete. This is really weird, I tried tens of different methods till now, but no result.

Comment: Very long strings probably are just truncated when printed to avoid spamming the console.  Again: have you inspected the actual file that you're trying to read?  How did you compare your manually generated base64 output?  Fundamentally, what evidence supports your conclusion that `readAsBytesSync` is the problem and not something else?  Are you certain that the file itself is complete?  Without doing base64-encoding, have you observed `readAsBytesSync` returning bytes different than what's in the file?

Comment: How are you sending the data, can you show that part?

Comment: You are totally right. The debug window truncates the output. The problem is on the AWS side actually in whic I cannot regularly extract base64 string from lambda event. Many thanks, you made my day. Problem resolved - jamesdlin is a great guy. Also thanks to Claudi Redi.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113038/string-variable-cant-store-all-base64-decoded-string).

I thought at first it was in front-end(flutter) but upon hours of inspecting and research what happens is that the back-end (go lang) receiver's buffer reader closes it just before the whole base64 was sent through an API call.