# readAsBytesSync is incomplete

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Since I can't convert convert a file directly from url `(e.g File(url))`.

I am downloading the file and then use the temp file path.

I tried different files : images, pdfs and it's still incomplete.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
 Future<String> downloadFile() async {
    print(imgUrl);
    Dio dio = Dio();

    try {
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      await dio.download(imgUrl, "${dir.path}/${widget.name}.pdf",
          onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {});
      path = "${dir.path}/${widget.name}.pdf";
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progressString = "Completed";
      });
      if (path != null) {
        List<int> imageBytes = File(path).readAsBytesSync();
        print("NEW BYTE : $imageBytes");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return path;
  }
```

Comment: How are you determining that `readAsBytesSync()` is returning an incomplete file?  How have you concluded that `readAsBytesSync` is the problem?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62572652/.  Note that you can't expect `print()` to show all bytes because excessive output from `print()` will be automatically truncated.

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout this solution:-**
https://gist.github.com/Nitingadhiya/3e029e2475eeffac311ecd76f273941f

```
Uint8List? _documentBytes;
getPdfBytes() async {
   _documentBytes = await http.readBytes(Uri.parse('https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf'));
   return _documentBytes;
}

Future<void> readPDf() async {
 //Load the existing PDF document.
 Uint8List documentInBytes = await getPdfBytes();

 final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(inputBytes: documentInBytes);
 //Get the existing PDF page.
 final PdfPage page = document.pages[0];
 //Draw text in the PDF page.
 page.graphics.drawString('Hello World!', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 12), brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)), bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 150, 20));

 //Save the document.
 final List<int> bytes = await document.save(); //document.saveSync();
 await saveAndLaunchFile(bytes, 'Invoice.pdf');

 //Dispose the document.
 document.dispose();
}

Future<void> saveAndLaunchFile(List<int> bytes, String fileName) async {
 //Get the storage folder location using path_provider package.
 String? path;
 if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isWindows) {
   final Directory directory = await path_provider.getApplicationSupportDirectory();
   path = directory.path;
 } else {
   path = await PathProviderPlatform.instance.getApplicationSupportPath();
 }
 final File file = File(Platform.isWindows ? '$path\\$fileName' : '$path/$fileName');
 await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
 if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
   //Launch the file (used open_file package)
   // await open_file.OpenFile.open('$path/$fileName');
 } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
   await Process.run('start', <String>['$path\\$fileName'], runInShell: true);
 } else if (Platform.isMacOS) {
   await Process.run('open', <String>['$path/$fileName'], runInShell: true);
 } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
   await Process.run('xdg-open', <String>['$path/$fileName'], runInShell: true);
 }
}
```