# Why is the base64 string not showing completely?

Tags: flutter, dart

So this is my code

```
_image1 = File(pickedImage.path);
List<int> imageBytes = _image1.readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = base64.encode(imageBytes);
_shcpImg = base64Image;
```

But when I print the string `_shcpImg`, it just prints a part of the string, because when I copy and paste that base64 into an online converter, it only shows a really tiny piece of the image. So the thing is that the string is not showing completely or somehow the base64 encoder is not working well.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Also you can try to import ```dart: developer``` and use ```log(...)``` to print test, is it working ?

Comment: ikerfah im using VS code

Comment: Android (and I think iOS too) limits the amount of spew printed, so very long messages will be truncated.  If you want to observe a base64 string, don't use `print`-style debugging.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66113038/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62572652/ and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, since you are using VsCode and you can't print the full string (long string)

You can use `log` from `dart: developer`,

if the string is REALLY LONG, There is a workaround to fix this, the idea is to divide your long string into small pieces (in the example, 800 length for each piece) using `RegExp` and then iterate into the result and print each piece.

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer also, maybe it will help someone else in the future